# ¿Cómo puedo identificar palabras en negrita en un word con Python?

Tags: python, procesamiento-de-texto

Tengo un diccionario de definiciones de toda la vida en word, en el que las palabras a definir están en negrita, y la definición de cada palabra sin negrita a continuación. Todo seguido y en texto.

Necesito que Python identifique qué palabra es la que se define (la que está en negrita), y que las palabras que hay a continuación hasta la siguiente negrita, son las palabras que se utilizan para definir a esta primera.

El fin de esto es conseguir crear una matriz de NxN (Siendo N el número total de palabras a definir del diccionario), en las que para cada palabra se identifique qué otras palabras del diccionario se utilizan para definir a cada palabra.

No tengo ni idea de por donde coger el problema. Cualquier ayuda me servirá mucho sin duda.

Muchísimas gracias!!

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El único paquete que he usado para manejar docx es [python-docx](https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/). Si tu estructura es tal como cuentas una palabra en negrita (bold) seguida de un texto (definición) y así sucesivamente, no te debe entrañar mucha dificultad parsearlo.

La clave estaría en iterar sobe todos los objetos `docx.text.run.Run` y obtener aquellos con atributo `bold` como `True`.

Por ejemplo, una forma genérica que funcionaría aunque las definiciones estén en distintos párrafos sería:

```
import docx


doc = docx.Document('test.docx')

defs = {}
palabra = None
aux = []

for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        if run.bold:
            if palabra is not None:
                defs[palabra] = "".join(aux)
            palabra = run.text
            aux.clear()
        else:
            aux.append(run.text)

if palabra is not None:
    defs[palabra] = "".join(aux)
```

Para un texto de la forma:

> **byte**Unidad de información compuesta generalmente de ocho bits
>   **documento**Escrito en que constan datos fidedignos o susceptibles de ser empleados como tales para probar algo

obtendríamos algo como:

> ```
> >>> defs
>
> {'byte': 'Unidad de información compuesta generalmente de ocho bits',
>  'documento': 'Escrito en que constan datos fidedignos o susceptibles de ser empleados como tales para probar algo'}
> ```